# iPhone Simulator not working when encountering NSFileManager defaultManager

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator, nsfilemanager

I'm quite new to iOS development but this has got me absolutely baffled...

My app is doing a simple check if a file exists, like so:

```
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[self.countDatabase.fileURL path]]) {....
```

This worked fine last week and it still works perfectly fine on the iOS device itself. But when the iPhone simulator gets to this line of code, it just... stops. No errors, it doesn't freeze, it just stops. I can start other actions in it but it never completes what was started before. I don't get it. The only thing on this macbook that's changed since last week is that I updated OSX to 10.8.2 and update to iTunes 10.7.

Has anyone ever encountered this or have some idea how I can further debug this? If I step through the code, I get to this line and it just stops stepping through things. It's as if the simulator thinks that it's done.

Answer (score 0):

since I used lots of times:

```
 [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"file.pdf"]]]
```

It seems that `[self.countDatabase.fileURL path]` is returning wrong value as a path. I would `NSLog` it to see what is containing.

Comment: When I debug and look at the path I see what appears to be a valid path on the local filesystem.

Comment: Oh, I didn't read that in device is working fine. So this seems to me a simulator issue. Did you try removing the app (to clear any path made with the app id)?

Comment: I've reset the simulator, in fact, I've since removed and reinstalled xcode... *shrug*. The problem seems to occur during a openWithCompletionHandler call for my coredata document. It works fine on the device (meaning it actually executes my block of code to run on success, whereas in the simulator it does not do that.